# Micro USB power for charging

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

I have a USB battery pack, and separately some modest solar cells. I'd like to build an interface to allow those solar cells to charge the battery pack. Battery pack charge input is vi micro-USB (it provides output via USB-A). I've been wallowing around on seemingly circular searches trying to get much confidence about how to a) wire this up, b) needed voltages, and c) whether there's some kind of magic that allows the power-recipient to control the supplied voltage in some way (I've found things that talk about USB having multiple voltage options for its supply line, though I *think* this only relates to newer USB-3 things that are designed for high current, and I'm fairly sure this isn't such a device).

At this point I believe, but would appreciate confirmation or correction, that I should simply provide a flat 5v on the "red" wire (assuming that when I split open an existing USB-A to micro USB cable, they have adopted the conventional color for V-BUS), and that voltage is the only option for pre-USB-C devices.

Can anyone tell me if this is correct, or alternatively how I should configure this, and/or point me at a specification that I might be able to follow with some confidence?

Comment: 5V is indeed the standard for VBUS on a type A connector. For higher voltages you need to implement USB-PD. It's also the default for the type C connector but you need to implement resistors in order for it to appear.

Comment: Reasonably understandable description here on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#USB_Power_Delivery)

Comment: @Finbarr thanks! The PD and C stuff is probably what was confusing me. Seems easy enough for simple stuff. Thanks for the pointer to the wikipedia, that looks helpful too so long as I can strip away the stuff that's not pertinent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of those power packs are designed to plug into and charge from standard 5 volt USB power.

Give them a steady 5 volts and that's it. The power pack will take the current it requires (the way most *but not all* loads work).

Now if you want to get into USB-PD, don't reinvent the wheel. Just arrange your solar cells to supply 12 volts, and then use an off-the-shelf USB-PD supply that plugs into the cigarette lighter socket in a car.